# Crystal Reports "Export to PDF" not working - "Cannot find the QE property"

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm adding this question and answer to help other developers as it wasn't particularly easy to figure it out.

A legacy app I'm maintaining uses Crystal Reports 9 and since a few weeks ago on some users the "Export to PDF" button stopped working, giving different errors, one being "Cannot find the QE property".

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be related to a Windows Update, KB3102429, that was installed on some computers. Uninstalling it solves the issue!

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102429

Answer (score 1):

i resolved it by installing crystal for VS
then uninstalled
then reinstalled crystal runtime - restart needed

Answer (score 0):

In this my case when occurred page size in first load different to page size once printing time, first time i have 11 pages, i want to export last page, while in export total page is 10 page. Therefore, there is no page 11 that wants to be export.